# Using Matplotlib animation inside event handler

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have an animation I would like to fire each time the user presses a specific key. I have data that represents an animated plot (so one different plot per frame) and an empty plot, so the idea is that when you press `R` (for example) the animated plot runs, and if you press `R` again it runs again. The following code works:

```
### Lots of code before

fig = plt.figure()
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

where `animate` is a function I wrote. When I run this the Matplotlib window pops up and the animation runs over and over. This is fine, but I'd like the animation to fire on command, so I did this:

```
### Lots of code before

def press(event):
    if event.key == "r":
        print("r") # for debugging purposes
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", press)
plt.show()
```

The event registers as evidenced by the `print`, but nothing happens, just an empty plot window. Now, I read that this doesn't work because the animation object needs to stay alive after the function ends, so I added `global anim` to the event handler before I create the animation object, and now when I press `R` the program simply stops and the plot window closes.

The `global` approach works fine if the `FuncAnimation` call is inside some function, like this:

```
def f():
    global anim
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate)

f()
```

but not inside the event handler.

What should I do? How do I create an animation object inside the event handler and make it stay alive?

Update: apparently what causes the crash is having `blit=True` in the `FuncAnimation`call (which I didn't include in my example since I thought it was irrelevant). Setting `blit=False` stops the crashing, but still nothing happens when I trigger the event.

Comment: What version of mpl + backend?

Comment: @tacaswell: the Anaconda 64-bit package for Windows. It includes Python 3.5, Matplotlib 1.5.3.

Comment: which version of qt?

Comment: @tacaswell The backend is Qt5Agg; the QT version is 5.6.0 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately a change from qt4 -> qt5 is that any exceptions raised on by python in callbacks from the event loop (which is where the keypress callbacks are handled) result in the program quitting rather than printing a traceback.  Without code that actually shows the problem it is hard to provide better than generic advice.  When debugging things like this I tend to resort to _lots_ of print statements :)

Comment: @tacaswell your comment inspired me to switch to the Tkinter backend and it worked this time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep a live refernce to the animation object or it (and it's timers) get garbage collected. See http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/animation_api.html#animation

It is odd that the `global` technique does not work in the event callback, but if that is the case, the best approach is probably to make a small helper class

```
class AnimManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.anim = None

    def __call__(self, event):
        fig = make_a_figure_function()
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate)

am = AnimManager()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", am)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly it didn't help. See my edit: the code no longer crashes, but it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but hopefully it may be of help to anyone with the same problem: inspired by @tacaswell's comment above I tried switching backends to TkAgg, and now it works. Maybe it's a bug with QT?